# jQuery conflict? Using WPL

Tags: jquery, wordpress, wpl

```
TypeError: jQuery('ul.tabs').tabs is not a function. 
(In 'jQuery('ul.tabs').tabs('> .tabs_content')', 'jQuery('ul.tabs').tabs' is undefined)
```

The gallery isn't showing up properly [here](http://rhinolc.com/r/properties/11-House-For-Sale-1030-Pujo-Lake-Charles-Calcasieu-Louisiana-United-States-70601-4Bathrooms-USD399900/).

I have updated the theme and I'm using the latest version of WPL.

Not a jQuery guru, but it's some kind of conflict. Any thoughts?

Much appreciated!

Comment: It's not a conflict. Something is missing, because there are not function called `tabs`.  I think the `jquery-ui` is the missing library.

Comment: you should avoid using links, instead isolated the code in question, and paste it here.

Comment: @lolka_bolka, same thought,  jquery != to jquery ui

Comment: Thanks.. first time post!

Comment: WPL is a WordPress plugin for showing real estate properties. Thanks rnevius for the edit.

Comment: When enqueuing your script in `functions.php` add a `jquery-ui-tabs` dependency. For instance `wp_enqueue_script('theme_js', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/theme.js', array('jquery', 'jquery-ui-tabs'));` where theme.js is your theme javascript file, and in the array are the dependencies. Look [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Link_a_Theme_Script_Which_Depends_on_jQuery) for detail.

Comment: That worked. Found the correct js file to load and now working properly. You guys saved my day. `wp_enqueue_script('theme_js', get_template_directory_uri().'/lib/scripts/tabs.min.js', array('jquery', 'jquery-ui-tabs'));`
'